# Why does running my linear regression result in negative R2 in pipeline, but not outside pipeline?

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, pipeline

I'm getting some funky results whilst running a linear model in a pipeline, and I'm hoping someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

- First I ran a simple linear regression without any hyper parameter tuning and I found a R^2 of 0.83.
- I then tried to run linear regression in a pipeline but my R^2 got down to -4!
- Finally I ran a Ridge regression in my pipeline, I get an R^2 of
  0.95.

Why does my pipeline linear regression give such poor results???
(Note: I ran this model on the WHO life expectancy dataset)

This is my code for both pipelines.

**My Linear Regression pipeline**

```
#setup the pipeline steps
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.NaN, strategy='most_frequent')), 
         ('reg', LinearRegression())]
          
# Create the pipeline: pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

# Create train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)


# Fit the pipeline to the training set: 
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the labels of the test set
y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)

print("R^2: {}".format(pipeline.score(X_test, y_test)))
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Root Mean Squared Error: {}".format(rmse))
```

**My Ridge regression pipeline**

```
#setup the pipeline steps
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.NaN, strategy='most_frequent')), 
         ('ridge', Ridge(normalize=True))]
          
# Create the pipeline: pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

#Define hyperparameters and range of Grid Search
parameters = {"ridge__alpha": np.linspace(0,1,100)}

# Create train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# run cross validation
cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid = parameters, cv=3)

# Fit the pipeline to the training set: 
cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the labels of the test set
y_pred = cv.predict(X_test)

# Compute and print R^2 and RMSE
print("R^2: {}".format(cv.score(X_test, y_test)))
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Root Mean Squared Error: {}".format(rmse))
print("Tuned Model Parameters: {}".format(cv.best_params_))
```

Note: The "normalize=True" argument does not change the outcome.

Your thoughts are very welcome! :)

Comment: I hope you mean `R^2` of `0.4`. `-4` is not possible :). But you are doing many things differently between these two cases. Most importantly, the models are very different (simple linear regression vs ridge regression). Why should they have the same R^2?

Comment: No, it was actually -4 and the RMSE was huge…. I'm not surprised the Ridge Regression and Simple lineair regression give different outputs, but I am surprised that the output of the Linear regression in my pipeline is different from the one outside… That is why I'm wondering if my pipeline is correct? I also shared my Ridge regression to show that I can build functioning pipelines. What do you think?

Comment: As I understand the problem is that the same `LinearRegression` model built using pipelines and not using pipelines gives different results? Can You share some sample data and comparison of this methods? I assume ridge regression example is not relevant to the main problem.

Comment: That was indeed the problem.... Unfortunately today none of my models run anymore. I am not sure what went wrong. Similar pipelines do run in other datasets, so I'm affraid the error is in my data. I now get a value error (ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').).  when I try to run my Linear Regression pipeline or Ridge regression pipeline Missing data shouldnt' be the issue because I use imputer, my largest value is 200.000 so that also should't be the issue. Do you have a suggestion what may go wrong?

Comment: If problem may be located in data as You suggest then test linear model on very small sample of data and then enclose this sample of data in question. Also maybe consider removing section dedicated to ridge regression as this is only secondary topic.